# Assigning values to parametrized arrays in Verilog

Tags: syntax, verilog, register-transfer-level

Suppose I have the following module definition,

```
module foo(b)
input b;
parameter length = 8;

reg [length-1:0] dummy ;
```

Now, I want to assign values to this dummy array. For instance I want to make it all 1s. If the length was not parameterized, I could do this,

```
always @(posedge b)
 dummy <= 8'hFF;
```

But when the length is parameterized, I would hope to do this,

```
always @(posedge b)
 dummy <= length'hFFFF //won't even compile. even if it did, how many F's should there be?
```

How can I assign ones (or zeroes) to an entire array whose length is parameterized? Or more generally, how can I assign values while specifing the length of a parameterized array?

Comment: Do you really mean packed arrays? `reg [length-1:0] dummy;` Your declaration was unpacked, and you cannot have those kind of assignments to unpacked array, parameterized or not.

Comment: @dave_59 My bad, I just fixed the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
always @(posedge b)
 dummy <= ~1'b0;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that Verilog extends operands before applying operators when they are in context-determined expressions.

In SystemVerilog, you can write

```
always @(posedge b)
 dummy <= '1;
```

Comment: What difference would writing ```dummy <= ~0;``` make, if any?

Comment: No difference in this expression. But do realize that `0` is the same as writing `32'sd0`

Answer (score 5):

You can do bit extension:

```
always @ (posedge b)
  dummy <= {length{1'b1}};
```

What is inside the {} is extended by "parameter-1", would be the same as having:

```
always @ (posedge b)
  dummy <= {1'b1,1'b1,1'b1,1'b1....};
```